# What are some sound multivariate GARCH models with proven mathematical/statistical properties?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, references, garch, volatility-forecasting

Some popular multivariate GARCH models such as BEKK and DCC have been criticized for the nonexistence of the corresponding stochastic processes and (if I interpret that correctly) the following meaninglessness of the parameter estimates; see e.g. [McAleer (2019a)](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/12/2/66) and [McAleer (2019b)](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/12/2/61). **I wonder what are some multivariate GARCH models that do not suffer from such problems and have been shown to be fundamentally sound.** References would be appreciated.

According to two broad surveys ([Bauwens et al, 2006](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jae.842); [Silvennoinen & Teäsvirta, 2009](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-71297-8_9)) of multivariate GARCH models, there are plenty of candidates to choose from. I am interested in which ones among them, or among newer ones, I could use with a clean conscience (from the statistical perspective).

**References:**

- Bauwens, L., Laurent, S., & Rombouts, J. V. (2006). [Multivariate GARCH models: a survey](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/jae.842). *Journal of Applied Econometrics, 21*(1), 79-109.
- McAleer, M. (2019a). [(Non-) Existence, Mathematical (IR-)Regularity and (Non-) Asymptotic Properties of the Full BEKK Dynamic Conditional Covariance Model](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/12/2/66). *Journal of Risk and Financial Management, 12*(2), 66
- McAleer, M. (2019b). [What They Did Not Tell You about Algebraic (Non-) Existence, Mathematical (IR-) Regularity, and (Non-) Asymptotic Properties of the Dynamic Conditional Correlation (DCC) Model](https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/12/2/61). *Journal of Risk and Financial Management, 12*(2), 61.
- Silvennoinen, A., & Teräsvirta, T. (2009). [Multivariate GARCH models](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-71297-8_9). In *Handbook of Financial Time Series* (pp. 201-229). Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.

Comment: Has the same type of objection been made for univariate models in the extended "X"-GARCH family?

Comment: @Michael, I don't know. Has it?

Comment: Don't know...what about the other question---has the existence been explicitly shown for all the variations/extensions of GARCH? Does existence follow trivially from the model specification in all cases?

Comment: @Michael, I guess existence has not been shown for all variations of univariate GARCH, but at least for some models I expect it has been shown. Some capable French mathematicians like Francq and Zakoian have worked on GARCH models, I guess they were rigorous all the way. I am not quite on that level (to put it mildly) and have struggled with the intuitive understanding of existence: see ["What is meant by existence of a (discrete-time) stochastic process?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/407725).

Comment: Interesting that even the univariate case existence has not been fully addressed (so it seems). Will see if I could add couple examples to the other question at some point.

Comment: @Michael, that would be lovely! The less technical they will be, the easier to digest, I think.